# How to download Amazon MWS Customisation fields

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm looking into how to process customisation fields for Amazon orders and according to their [MWS API Docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Datatypes.html#BuyerCustomizedInfo), if a customer chooses to personalise his order, then a URL to download this data comes down in the Order Item XML's BuyerCustomizedInfo node:

```
<OrderItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ASIN>ABC123</ASIN>
...
  <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
  <BuyerCustomizedInfo>
    <CustomizedURL>https://zme-caps.amazon.com/t/ABC123/ABC123/1</CustomizedURL>
  </BuyerCustomizedInfo>
</OrderItem>
```

My client has given me two such orders to look at, and when I click on those links all I get is

> NoSuchURL: Url id 'ABC123' has expired or does not exist!

I know that the ZIP will contain JSON which I will have to parse and may also contain references to SVGs, and that I must also make the code extra robust when dealing with customisation fields.

Am I getting this error because these links are time sensitive or one time use only? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

First off I'm not a Developer, I'm an Amazon Seller - I found your question while doing research as I'm trying to figure out what is possible and sketch a plan for a similar system and then hire a Developer.

I've pasted some info that I had found from the US below - the implementation of Amazon Custom in the European Marketplaces may not be the same as in the US though.

In general it is very hard to get good info on anything to do with Amazon Custom and it seems to have a messed up logic of its own - feel free to ask anything though and I will help if I can.

---

First of all, make sure you have the most up to date Amazon MWS Orders API SDK. If you don’t and refuse to update, you can make a reports API for orders, and that’ll include the ZIP URL, but you’ll have to parse it and life will be hell.

Next, for the order, call ListOrderItems which you probably already do. You’ll see the customization in the response XML under BuyerCustomizedInfo -> CustomizedURL.

This is a ZIP. Download the zip using CURL, put plenty of checks and fallbacks in place because it will fail sometimes.

Extract the ZIP to a folder. Inside that folder there will be a json file.

Parse that JSON file and you’ll probably know where to go from there for putting that information into your system.

Depending on how you’ve configured your product, there may also be an SVG file that you’ll want to parse to get some customization info. Specially json->{‘version3.0’}->customizationInfo->surfaces (each surface)->areas. Each area should be a text line or image. At least that is how it is for how we’ve set up products.

As always, put lots of checks, try catches, fallbacks, and error alerts.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this post really answers the question. It provides "generic" instructions only.

Comment: This answers the question. MWS API is working exactly this way.

Comment: I've ended up trying to learn to do this for myself, but (ironically) I've hit a brick wall at the same stage! I can get the BuyerCustomizedInfo -> CustomizedURL, but I cannot figure out how to download the zip file - @DanielWalter can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The links are time sensitive and expire after 6 months I think.
The links should be a little more complex and if that is exactly the link you are seeing it's incorrect.
You don't require any auth to download them and the easiest way to test them is via the MWS Scratchpad.